# OpenCL C++ bindings: waiting for a single cl::Event?

Tags: c++, opencl

Using the [OpenCL C++ bindings](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl.hpp) ([documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.1.pdf)), is it possible to have enqueued commands wait for only **one** `cl::Event`?

Let's take a look at `enqueueReadBuffer()`'s signature as an example:

```
cl_int cl::CommandQueue::enqueueReadBuffer(
   ...
   const VECTOR_CLASS<Event>* events = NULL,
   ... )
```

It expects a pointer to a `VECTOR_CLASS` (e.g. `std::vector`) of `cl::Event` and there is no overload for the case of a single `cl::Event`. Of course one could wrap a single `cl::Event` into a `VECTOR_CLASS` of size 1, but that does not seem to be a very good solution. I was wondering if there is a better solution, since waiting on a single `cl::Event` seems like a pretty common thing to do ...

Notice that this problem does not exist in the [OpenCL C API](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl.h) ([documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/)), where you pass a pointer to a `cl_event` and the number of `cl_event`s that are read.

```
cl_int clEnqueueReadBuffer ( 
    cl_command_queue command_queue,
    ...
    cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,
    const cl_event* event_wait_list,
    ... )
```

Comment: Is there any performance reason why you don't want to use a VECTOR_CLASS, or is it just personal preference?

Comment: It just seems superfluous to wrap every single `cl::Event` in a vector of size 1.

Comment: As far as I know, that is the only way. However, it is as efficient to read the first value of a vector, as to read a single value.

Comment: I ran into the same problem.  This is very poor binding design.  Also it's not obvious is cl::Event is copyable - i.e. can I declare cl::Event object and then add it to a vector when I want WORK_UNIT2 to wait for event from WORK_UNIT1.  Or do I have to create the vector and enqueue &my_vector[0] when adding WORK_UNIT1.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just execute `event.wait()` and then enqueue another event. See [this link](http://kosobucki.pl/cl_doc/classcl_1_1Event.html#abb1dccd98dc3cee29bd6638bc71005cb).

Comment: I think the original Robert's question was about how to pass Event instead of vector of Events in **enqueueReadBuffer** rather than how to wait for a single event. I think that you have to use vector :-(